# Issues showing images with paperclip using collections Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am having an issue getting a collection of user posted pics to show using paperclip. From the code you'll see that the app allows either a link or a file to be shown. It Works just fine showing all on pics/index but the papercliped files won't show in the user collection users/1/pics. I believe it has something to do with the way Rails puts the path in the image_tags.

**Routes**

```
   resources :users do
    member do
      get :pics
      get :toggle_approve
    end
```

**User/show**

```
<% if @user.pics.any? %>

  Pics Posted: <%= link_to @pics.count, pics_user_path(@user) %>
    <br />

  <% else %>
  No Pics Posted!<br />
<% end %>
```

**Pics/index**

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
    <% if !image.image_link.nil? %>

    <li><%= link_to image_tag(image.image_link, size:"100x200"), pic_path(image), class: "th" %><br>
    <% else %>

    <li><%= link_to image_tag(image.image.url(:large), size:"100x200"), pic_path(image), class: "th" %><br>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

I figured it out. The users view for the pics /user/1/pics had similar code as the pics/index. When I added the functionality for the paperclip uploaded file, I didn't update the user pics view with the same logic to determine if it was a link or a file.